# Is there any relation ill-posed problem and not Normal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I am trying to understand different aspect associated with ill-posed problem. Can we claim that an ill-posed problem $Ax=b$ means that the matrix $A$ is not normal? Further, can we claim that if $A$ is normal we cannot have an ill-posed problem?

Answer (score 0):

A problem $Ax=b$ is ill-conditioned if the condition of the matrix is "large".

The condition is calculated with some norm $n(A)$ and defined as

$n(A)n(A^{-1})$. So, the matrix needs not to be normal, it just must have a
"small" condition.